# I can't play downloaded music on my media player

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, file-transfer, dell-latitude, music-management

I just got a used laptop from a relative – a Dell Latitude E4300 with Windows 7 Enterprise. This is because my old desktop is using the now unsupported XP software.

So I'm transferring files from the old to the laptop via USB. I just did my music and now I can't seem to able to listen to it in the laptop media player.

It says something like "mitigation license error - update your Internet Explorer". I didn't have problems listening to music on the desktop... And when I go to the Explorer downloads, Microsoft tells me I have their latest browser.

So what exactly is the problem then?

Comment: Try running it using a different player, like foobar2000 or VLC.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a [Digital Rights Management (DRM)](https://www.eff.org/issues/drm) issue.

Comment: But if I bought the CD, can't I use it for my personal use? I'm not trying to give it to anyone. And I deleted the tracks from the old desktop. Do I need to download again to the laptop? Sorry by the way, I don't think I'm doing this chain right.